# Ionic if else statement to display div

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using the ionic framework to make an app. I want to do an if/else statement to display div in html . l am taking data from navigation url from page 1 to page 2 . in page 2 l use activated route params to get data from page 1 .

Sometimes the data coming from url like that `mypage/iaw/null` so l want to check if string coming null hide div .

what i did

```
 public myFlag: boolean = false;
  id : any

      constructor(private nav : NavController,private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute) {
                    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {

                      this.id = params['id'];
                    });

            if (this.id=="null") {
                this.myFlag = true

            }else{
              this.myFlag = false
            }
```

html

```
  <div *ngIf="myFlag">

    <ion-button expand="block" fill="outline"color="success"  (click)="navigate(id)">Flight route</ion-button>

  </div>      
  <div *ngIf="!myFlag">

    No data 
  </div>
```

my url example

```
localhost/flightserachdetails/IA172/Isfahan/1555496100/CR9/scheduled/Iraqi%20Airways/IAW/null
```

Comment: this.id is null as string or that's actual null?

Comment: some time coming null in url if no string . like that `scheduled/IraqiAirways/IAW/null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should change your constructor code something like this

```
constructor(private nav : NavController,private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.myFlag = this.id == "null";
        console.log(this.myFlag);
    });
}
```

The main thing here is to initialize "id" field inside ativate route subscribtion handler.

However, the best way to implement routing in angular is to use RouterModule. Checkout this link for more details https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: l put  if else statement in activated Route and he is working fine. thank you for key answer

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the if else statement like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="myFlag;else other_content">
  <ion-button expand="block" fill="outline"color="success (click)="navigate(id)">Flight route</ion-button>
</div>
<ng-template #other_content>
  No data
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement if else like this so no need to write the separate ngIf for checking else condition

```
 <div *ngIf="myFlag != null; elseCondition">
    <ion-button expand="block" fill="outline"color="success"  (click)="navigate(id)">Flight route</ion-button>
  </div>      
  <ng-template #elseCondition>
    No data 
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: i just edit my answer please try with != null so it will also check undefined as well as null

Comment: unfortunately smae problem

Comment: what is a console log of myFlag ?